# Is there a proper way to use mathdesign fonts in amsart?

Tags: fonts, amsart, mathdesign

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

gives

```
Package mathdesign/mdbch Warning: Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdbch
```

Is there a 'proper' way to use `mathdesign` fonts in `amsart`?

```
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}
```

produces an error.

I know there are hacks, not looking for those. (I need to share my files with co-authors so they better be clean, if I want my colleagues to tolerate my font extravaganza.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the option `noamsfonts` to `amsart` is bugged, because `amsfonts.sty` declares the font `AMSb` that is referenced in `amsart.cls` nonetheless.  The solution is to declare it yourself before loading the class:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
This is text.
\begin{equation*}
  \int_a^b \Omega(t_1) \partial t_1
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This has to be done *before* `\documentclass` since the bug occurs within the class file itself.  Fortunately, in some way mysterious to me (I know nothing about LaTeX and fonts) this font can indeed be referenced even first thing in the file.

That's a nice font, by the way.

Comment: Only the second line is necessary. It's surely a bug in the AMS classes; the msbm font is used only to provide a correct `\DH` glyph when OT1 encoding is used. Unfortunately, being due to an `\edef` executed during the processing of the class file it's not possible to correct it without modifying the class itself.

Comment: Well, this is probably as clean as we can get.
Just hope that `amsart.cls` will get fixed eventually..

Comment: @David: Barbara Beeton is the person to submit this too.  She watches this site for bug reports, too.